# Float Array is not converted to int: Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, floating-point, integer

I have a float numpy array x, which contains values like, 0, .5, 1, 1.5,etc. I want to convert the float values into integers based on some equation and store them in a new array, newx. I did this,

```
newx=np.zeros(x.shape[0])
    for i in range (x.shape [0]):
        newx[i]=  ((2*x[i]) +1)
    print(newx, v)
```

However, when printing xnew, I get values like

```
(array([   1.,    2.,    3.,    4.,    5.,    6.,    7.,    8.,    9.,
         10.,   11.,   12.,   13.,   14.,   15.,   16.,   17.,   18.])
```

newx must be used in some process, and it must be integer, when I want to use it in that process, I get an error stating that it must be of integer or Boolean type. Can anyone please tell me what mistake I've done?

Thank You.

Comment: Cast it to an int type: `print(newx.astype(np.int), v)`.

Comment: Integer types can in general be automatically cast to float type, but the other way around is trickier, and thus not automagically done by Python/numpy.

Comment: @Evert, thanks a lot, this newx.astype(np.int) is woking perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy is specifically designed for array manipulation. Try not to iterate over a numpy array like you did. You can read about how numpy datatypes are a little different than inbuilt datatypes. This leads to much higher run times.

Anyways Here is a working code for your problem

```
newx=x*2+1
newx=numpy.int16(newx)      # as easy as this. ;)
```

Comment: Why do you use `int16` here?  I don't see anything in the OP suggesting that these are particularly small ints.  BTW, I'm surprised that simply passing `numpy.int16` an array works here; the usual advice is to use the `asarray` function or the `astype` method for type conversion.

Comment: Well you are right @MarkDickinson but the point of the answer was to teach why numpy arrays should not be iterated. Thanks for the advice though.